# Automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show there are infinitely many automorphisms of the group $\mathbb{Q}^*$.

I am not sure how show this.  If we were dealing with ring automorphisms $\varphi:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, then the fact that $\varphi(1)=1$  makes such a ring automorphism unique.  However, how can we show that with groups that there are inifinitely many such automorphisms.

Comment: It might help to start by figuring out the abstract structure of $\mathbb{Q}^{\ast}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: $$\mathbb{Q}^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/ 2\mathbb{Z}) \oplus \bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}$$

where the direct sum is indexed over the primes.

Comment: I think this would also show that there are _uncountably_ many automorphisms of $\langle \mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot \rangle$. $\hspace{1 in}$

Comment: There has to be simpler way of looking at this problem. I haven't seen the presented direct sum before. How do you get it?

Comment: Think of prime decomposition! The first factor is the sign $\pm$.

Comment: @Galois, that's the fundamental theorem of arithmetic applied to $\mathbb Q$, that is, to the numerator and denominator of a fraction.

Comment: @RickyDemer: You are right. By the way $\mathbb Q$ also has uncountably many subrings, for similar reasons.